# Adding Publications/Researcher's Publications to Organization Unit

Tags: dspace

How can I add Publications/Researcher's Publications to Organization Unit in Dspace CRIS?

Edit:
[The following image shows that publications is not listed under orgunit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIYbT.png)

[But the following image shows how researchers are listed under people tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAtI1.png)

If anyone can help me with a short answer how can I make publications visible under publications tab in orgunit view page.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [no attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your tries help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and illustrate the problems your are encountering in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This link explains  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

DSpace-CRIS allows you to configure the exact data model for your CRIS/RIMS. This mean that the relation between OrgUnits and Publications can be of different nature depending on your use cases/ultimate goals and configuration.
For example the following relations [1] can be configured:

- direct: to list publications that has been founded/supported by an organisation, such as working paper or department series. In such case the best practice is to add a metadata to the publication (like dc.description.sponsorship) linked to the orgunit and use inverse relation to list the publications under the orgunit page
- indirect: to list publications authored by researchers affiliated with the department. In such case an inverse relation need to be configured and the publication only need to hold a link to the researcher profile (usually dc.contributor.author)

Both examples are included out-of-box in the dspace-cris configuration, see
direct: https://github.com/4Science/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x_x-cris/dspace/config/spring/cris/cris-relationpreference.xml#L39

indirect: https://github.com/4Science/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x_x-cris/dspace/config/spring/cris/cris-relationpreference.xml#L31

Please note that also more complex relations like a "direct" research affiliation where the publications are listed in the orgunit page depending on the specific affiliation used by the researcher to sign the paper are possibile, for that you need to configure a "nested metadata" [2] and use the nested affiliation to build the inverse relation.

[1] https://wiki.duraspace.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=78163308#Custompresentation&dynamiccomponents-CRISComponents

[2] https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACECRIS/Nested+metadata+in+DSpace+items

Comment: Hello, please can you look to the example in my question and give me a short answer to solve the problem